# How can I replace "Price" with "Hourly rate" in wp custom css

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I replace "Price" with "Hourly rate" in wp custom css Price

Comment: How can I replace "Price" with "Hourly rate" in wp custom css <label class="hp-field__label hp-form__label"><span>Price</span></label>

Comment: please provide some more context. Are you trying to change the text content of a label? If so, it's not something you can do with css.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 label.hp-field__label.hp-form__label span {
     display: none;
 }
 label.hp-field__label.hp-form__label {
     position: relative;
 }
 label.hp-field__label.hp-form__label:before {
     content: ' Hourly rate';
 }
```